# How can I create my excel template for financial analysis

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export

I am not so familiar with how programming works (only a few attempts with Java) and since i am currently studying at a gymnasium (with focus on economics) i would like some help for how i can create an excel-template for my needs. However i can not figur out how to do so. I know how some of the basic macros functions in excel, but i would like do the following for my template:

1) Input some data (i think manually would be to prefer since i am often working with pictures). The data is some diffrent numbers form an annually report.

2) The data should then be used to calculate some different financial key figures (i know how to do this as well).

**I don't know how to do the following**

3) When the key figures have been calculated and the change from year to year also have been calculated, i would like to use some basic sentences to comment on the numbers: E.g. "The key figure xxxx has gone up by xx% over xx% years. This development is caused by the xx... [and so on]"

3.1) I would like the template to be able to comment on change over the key figures over the entire period, the biggest changes over the period (both ups and downs), the lowest and highest point on the period.

4) Export the text with the comments to a word document from the excel-spreadsheet.

I don't know which commands/functions i would need to use and how to use them if it is even possible to do in excel (but i'm willing to learn this by myself).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need programming. Simple formula within cells could do this.

```
="The key figure " & A1 & " has gone up by " & B1 & "%  over..."
```

You can use it with some IF statements that determines if the figure has gone up or down. IF(A1<0, "down","up"), this can give your commentary a bit of flexibility.

You probably don't need to export to word either, you can link the excel table to word. So every time the spreadsheet updates, then the content of word updates.